# Vim commands do not respond anymore

Tags: macos, vim, oh-my-zsh

Since yesterday, after I updated my macbook (system update, iterm update, oh_my_zsh and homebrew update), my Vim editor (the system one) does not quit anymore after typing `:q` or `:x`.

Most of the commands like saving don't work either, I sometimes can access the `:help` but I also can't quit it. I tried to install macvim in replacement but when I open it inside the command line with `mvim -v` I got the same issue.

The only way I found to quit it is to put it in the background with Ctrl+Z and force kill it, otherwise it won't close. I tried to find the solution online but most of the topics are about how to close it when it's working (for beginners) or are only about macvim.

Comment: When you type `:`, do you get the command line at the bottom? When you then type `q<Enter>`, what happens?

Comment: Yes the command line appears and I can type any command but when I press enter nothing happened